# Smallest $k \times l$ Grid That Guarantees to Find Four Monochromatic Points

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose each point in $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is colored with one of n given colors.

Find the Smallest $k$ and $l$ such that in any $k \times l$ grid one is guaranteed to find four monochromatic points that are vertices of a rectangle.

---

For the case of $n=1$, smallest $(k,l)$ would be obviously 2

For the case of $n=2$, I had found $4 \times 4 $ colored grid whcih still not making any monochromatic retangle :

$baba\\aabb\\abaa\\bbab
$

I could heuristically approach this problem, but I need more theretical background to solve this problem.

I need some advice.

Comment: Advice: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919432/every-point-of-a-grid-is-colored-in-blue-red-or-green-how-to-prove-there-is-a/1919497#1919497

Comment: Interesting blog: http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2009/11/17x17-challenge-worth-28900-this-is-not.html

Comment: Another question dealing with $n=2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310558/two-colouring-of-a-6-by-6-grid-without-a-monochromatic-rectangle/2412478#2412478

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ colours, we can make a long thin rectangle that is (I speculate) the smallest in area to force a rectangular set of same-coloured points: a grid of $(n+1)$ rows and $(n^3+n^2)/2 + 1$ columns.

Why? by the pigeonhole hole principle, there is at least one pair of same-coloured points in each column (of $n{+}1$ points). This pair can occur in $\binom {n+1}2 = n(n+1)/2$ positions, and we have a choice of $n$ colours for that pair. Thus once we have $n^2(n+1)/2 = (n^3+n^2)/2$ columns, all possibilities mst be fulfilled and one more column must produce a repeat of an earlier pair-position/colour combination, giving the required rectangle.

Comment: With $n+2$ points, you have at least two pair-position/colour combinations in each column.  There are $n {n+2 \choose 2} = (n+2)(n+1)n/2$ such combinations, so at most $(n+2)(n+1)n/4$ columns without having a monochromatic rectangle.  $n(n+2)(n+1)/4 < n^2(n+1)/2$ if $n > 2$.

Comment: Do you also consider diamond shaped rectangle too?

Comment: No, I'm just considering the rectangles aligned with the grid axes here. Skewed rectangles would be interesting, but significantly harder I feel.